# Get the first word of a file into a variable

Tags: ruby, file

I have a txt file and I want to extract only the first word of a line which contains the characters 'ath'.

```
File.open("myfile.txt").readlines.each do |line|
  if line =~ /ath/
   line.split.first
   puts line
$line = line.chomp

puts "Ok"
else
nil
end
end
```

`line.split.first` only works if the first word of the line is a match, because when I do the same in irb:

```
"im here to ask someting easy".split.first
```

The output is 'im'.

Answer (score 0):

If the first word in a line contains `ath` at any point

```
if line =~ /^\S*ath\S*/
```

Comment: I just solved it by the following `puts line.split.first` instead of `puts line`